# How is a React controlled component able to update?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In the Udemy "Modern React with Redux" course by Stephen Grider, an example is given wherein an input element's `value` is changed by an `onChange` event that sets that value. Specifically, the function looks like:

```
onChange= function(event){
    this.setState({ term: event.target.value})
}
```

and the input component looks like:

```
<input value = {this.state.term} />
```

I don't understand how `event.target.value` can be updated when to my eyes, state is "hardcoded" to `event.target.value`, ie when the component renders, an empty string. So if `state.term` is `""`, and input's `value` is overridden and "set" to be `state.term`, how is it able to update at all?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class SearchBar extends Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = { term: '' };
    }
    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <input 
                    value = {this.state.term}
                    onChange={event => this.setState({ term: event.target.value})} />
            </div>
        );
    }

}

export default SearchBar;
```

EDIT: Basically I think my question comes down to: Is that `<input>` element's `value` the same thing as `event.target.value`?

EDIT2: "Same thing" in the Javascript pass-by-reference sense of the word, i.e. are both things referencing the same value on the same object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `initial value = ''`
2. user presses `'r'`
3. you set state based on `event.target.value`. new `state.term` is `'r'`
4. state change triggers component update. the value of your input is `this.state.term` or `'r'`

To answer your edit:

Yes and no—the `value` will end up being the same as `event.target.value` but only because the value is using `state.term` that has been set to the value of `event.target.value`

`event.target.value` => determines => `state` => determines => `input[value]`

Comment: That much I get, I guess my question is, isn't the element pointed to by `event.target.value` the exact same element as `input.value` ? In the video he says "when you press r, the input's value hasn't changed. It only changes when the component rerenders."

Comment: That is correct. You can set a console.log in the render to prove it.

Comment: Then, `event.target.value` must not reference the same data as `input[value]`, right?

Comment: You're right, a `console.log()` proves it. Will accept your answer when it allows me, in 7 minutes.